# Showing custom contacts like iphone Address book

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, abaddressbook

I have tried

http://zcentric.com/2008/09/19/access-the-address-book/

And it works great. But now instead of AddressBook contact i have an array or other structure that have my contacts and i want to show it like an Address Book.

Do i need to make it all custom or is there any way i can use the AddressBook to show my contacts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using ABPeoplePickerNavigationController you can only fetch the contacts from the Ipad or Iphone Address Book.

If you want same functionality with your structure data you need to make it all Custom Using UITableView and other views.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue (show contacts in custom table view). Have you solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

read [Addressbook Programming Guid](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone.pdf) here from apple and you will get detailed answer of your question.